# Custom Player Moves in MK9

Tags: mortal-kombat-9

How do I re-map the player move keys into something that I like more?

I just want to casually play the game, without spending hours and hours memorizing what moves/combots each player has. I want to have some custom standards, for example, down-forward-punch would be a uniform custom standard for all players to fire a projectile, ect.

Comment: AFAIK you could remap a *button* to act like another button, but if a projectile is just forward-punch, I don't know how you could map the combo to be down-forward-punch. Certain combos are harder because the move itself is more devastating, so it should be more difficult to succeed at;  allowing players to remap combos would take away that angle of the game.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that you simply CAN NOT re-map the button combos in Mortal Kombat in order to make the game easier. The reason being because the combos are a PART of the game itself, introducing the challenge of stringing the right button mashes together in order to beat the hardest of opponents. It is what makes the game playable and fun.